# Best practise for merging several APIs

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

all experienced programmers.
I need advice on following.

What would be the best practice for the following problem

We have 2-3 apis of objects(apartments) (XML, JSON , SOAP , protocol doesn't matter  now)

Each of them has  several keypoints

a) Geographics - Each api has its own GeoDatabase with own names and IDs for the same cities and places

b) Each api has different ways of object attribute description ... like what a house has(swimming pool, wheelchair friendly, etc )

So what we need  is to import those data , merge them locally and search ....

What would be architecturally the right way of this type of problem solving....

A very near example is hotel search engines , where they are searching the data from 10-20 different systems. ...

So we need a similar stuff but totally on another type of objects.
Your notes , comments and answers are really appreciated .  Thanks a lot for participating.

Comment: In simple terms, you'd need to abstract where the data comes from, and then merging becomes very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic question, so sadly the answer will be pretty generic too. I would approach this problem so:

- Create `wrappers` for each of the various APIs, this will standardize the way in which they are internally invoked, making it easier to interact with them.
- Convert all the results into a `uniform format` (if possible), at least those fields which will be searched, sorted, acted upon.

If you persist this information into database, then it would be important to make the structure in such a way that it is easily query-able.

E.g. Storing a whole `JSON` string that defines a house into a field called description is not desirable. So is having fields created for each attribute of the house like `swimming pool (BOOLEAN yes/no)`. Instead have `key-value` fields like `attribute-name` and `attribute-value` which might have records like:

- swimming pool: YES
- No: of bedrooms: THREE

etc. You get the point. From my experience, as much you can have a unified data model into which you can mould the API value to be contained, the easier it will be to collate and compare them.

Comment: thanks @Raidenace .. So basically I see following 1) Make a standartized local database model 2) develop import mechanism for all APIs to the standartized local DB 3) Develop local search ....

Comment: yeah that would be the way to go..the main challenge is to make the database model and the wrapper mechanism standard. Once you do that, the rest (querying/sorting/best match) etc becomes way easier..All the best!